# How is this procedure of error propagation called?

Tags: error-analysis

I'm calculating the error on $\theta$ from given PDG values for
$f(\theta)=sin^2(2\theta) \pm \sigma_{f}$

Question: I'd like to calculate the errors (from the inverse function) as 
$$\sigma_{\theta}^{neg} = f - f^{-1}( f - \sigma_{f}^{neg} ) $$
$$\sigma_{\theta}^{pos} = f^{-1}( f + \sigma_{f}^{pos} ) - f $$

How is this procedure called officially? Does it have a commonly understood name?

I found [here](http://www.rit.edu/~w-uphysi/uncertainties/Uncertaintiespart2.html) the name "(e) [...] The simple approach.", which does not sound descriptive of the procedure.

Comment:
I'm not sure about the Gaussian error propagation in this case, since the error is asymmetric and the Gaussian approximation - which only gives a slope of the function at this point - does not describe the confidence interval well.

Comment: I think this question is more suitable for mathematics forum.

Comment: I'm asking for a field-specific term, so the forum is fitting.